# Why is the useDelimiter works like that?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have been trying to read a folder that contains any text files like this:

```
K.Love,CLE,miss,2
K.Leonard,TOR,miss,2
K.Love,CLE,make,1
...
```

I was doing some tests and for some reason when I use the `useDelimeter` to ignore or make the commas disappear, I encounter to a problem. I will show the code first:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inputFile = new File("src\\main\\resources\\games\\game1.txt");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
        reader.useDelimiter(",");
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String input = reader.next();
            names.add(input);
        }
        System.out.println(names.get(3));
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

What I expect when the console prints the arrayList at position 3 is:

```
K.Leonard
```

But instead of that it prints:

```
2
K.Leonard
```

When I change the position to number 4 it prints: `TOR` (Which is the name of a team).

Comment: There is no `,` between "2" and "K.Leonard", so why _would_ they fetched independently?

Comment: Oh, sorry for asking that but how do I fix that then? I'm pretty new into programming so sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Would be best to use a CSV library rather than Scanner at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your delimiter as `,`, meaning that the newline is no longer the delimiter. To get the behavior you expect, you could use a regex where either a `,` or a newline character are considered as delimiters:

```
reader.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
```

Comment: @UnNameSAS There's a serious problem with that regexp - it does not work on windows or windows-formatted text inputs. Try `",|\r?\n"`.